# Prove if there is a relation with a variable over time

Tags: regression, time-series, statistical-significance

I have a measurement from a parameter in different patients, which, from previous studies, should depend on time. The dependence could be of two forms: a) the variable decrease or b) the standard deviation of the measurements decrease.
Here is the plot of my measurements:
[image: Dependence of measurements of variable vs time]
I want to test if there is a relation over time (in theory should decrease magnitude and std).
I tried to do a linear regression, but as the picture shows, does not have many sense.
Is there any way to prove (or disprove) a relation over time in this case of measurements (by decreasing in magnitude or in deviation)?

Thanks,

Comment: I must say that all points are different patients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the relationship of the response over time need not just be linear. It is clear from the plot that at later times, the response has less variation. In addition, to the naked eye it looks like the mean of the response is also decreasing with time.

You might try the following:

(a) A transformation of the response. In other words, maybe time is not linearly related to y, but a function f(y). The most common transformation to try is the log transformation. This might take care of the non constant variance as well.

(b) Weighted regression. Since you have reason to believe the variance decreases over time, weighted regression might be the way to go.

(c) Polynomial fit. In addition to the previous two, you can also try fitting the regression of f(y) ~ x + x^2, since it looks like a quadratic fit might work as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem I see in the a visual assess is that at later times I have less variation but also less times. Do you believe that is it enough to do the regression and look at the confidence intervals to prove a decrease in variation? I was also considering to categorize the time as (for example) less than 6h and more than 6h, and do a t-test.

Comment: It depends on what kind of regression you are going to do. Just a simple linear regression of y ~ time is not going to be enough here. You might first want to try method (a) that I suggested and look at the fit.